# Entity Framework Relationships - Preferred Customer Address

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Assuming a Customer can have multiple addresses, but only one "Preferred" address. How can I make it so a property on the model class holds the preferred address only and work using lambda expression through another object, for example Order?

My model classes looks like this:

```
public class Cusotmer
{
   public virtual int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual HashSet<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
   public virtual Address PreferredAddress => Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Preferred)
}

public class Order
{
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

I would like this to work:

```
_context.Order.Where(x => x.Id == 20).Select(x => x.Person.PreferredAddress);
```

However I get an error saying:

> "The specified type member 'PreferredAddress' is not supported in LINQ
>   to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported."

Comment: Unfortunately, Entity Framework lacks formula properties as NHibernate has. It would be a great feature. If you routinely need this address, use a view model/DTO class and AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. It is not possible. Because you are using Linq to entities and these Linq statements are being converting to SQL query.So, there is no SQL equivalent for `PreferredAddress` property. The statement can't be converted to SQL query for this reason.

So, why don't you just try like this;

```
_context.Order.Where(x => x.Id == 20).Select(x => x.Person.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Preferred));
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault() alone won't give me the preferred address, maybe you meant FirstOrDefault(x => x.Preferred). Still, I don't like that solution, it's kind of ugly in my opinion. You did mention that the statement can't be converted to SQL query. What if I create a view that only brings the preferred address of all customers and map the property to that view? Will that work? How will that look in the Entity Configuration?

Comment: Yes I mean that. By the way, you can create a view to perform equivalent "PreferredAddress" for SQL. You should change entity or create a new entity to handle new view. And It will be difficult to manage. But I think, it would be over-engineering.